# Doubleclicking a checkbox?

Tags: .net, winforms, checkbox, double-click

I have a few checkboxes representing people.  Something like this:

```
[ ] George
[ ] Sam
[ ] Steve
[ ] Lisa
```

Each can be checked individually, and of course it's also possible to check none at all.  Code runs upon a change in check state.  That code uses the state of all checkboxes in its algorithm.

However, I would like them to ALSO behave like radiobuttons upon doubleclick.  That is, if you doubleclick one, it should become checked (regardless of its previous state) and all others will become un-checked.

Unfortunately there's no doubleclick event for a checkbox.  So clearly, I need to simulate a doubleclick by using mousedown (or mouse up) and a combination of timers, a stopwatch, etc.

Ultimately I know I'll find a solution through experimentation, so if I come up with a good solution I'll post it here.  But I have a feeling others have "simulated doubleclicks" before and if someone can post a good snippet for creating such an event from the mousedown event, that would be great.

P.S. The snippet should somehow involve `SystmInformation.DoubleClickTime`.  (This is the number of milliseconds that distinguishes a doubleclick from "two singleclicks".  It may be different from one machine to the next.)  Code for a single click should NOT run until that much time has elapsed, to ensure that a doubleclick isn't pending.  (Because as I mentioned, the code uses the state of all checkboxes.)

P.P.S. I'm using VB.NET Express 2008 for a winforms app, but I can probably translate form C# if needed and I figure this probably applies all across .NET platforms.

Comment: Is this about WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry, winforms and I'm using VB.NET I just added a PPS to my question.  I can translate a C# solution if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surgery is required, the CheckBox class was written to assume that standard click and double-click behavior is turned off.  This code worked, you'll have to give up on the MouseUp event:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyCheckBox
    Inherits CheckBox

    Public Sub New()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick Or ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, True)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(ByVal mevent As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        '' NOTE: do *not* call the base method
        MyBase.ResetFlagsandPaint()
    End Sub

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(True)> _
    Public Shadows Custom Event DoubleClick As EventHandler
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            AddHandler MyBase.DoubleClick, value
        End AddHandler
        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            RemoveHandler MyBase.DoubleClick, value
        End RemoveHandler
        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal value As EventArgs)
            Throw New InvalidOperationException  '' should never be raised by user code
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event
End Class
```

An event handler could look like this:

```
Private Sub MyCheckBox_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles MyCheckBox1.DoubleClick, MyCheckBox2.DoubleClick, MyCheckBox3.DoubleClick, MyCheckBox4.DoubleClick

    For Each box As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls
        box.Checked = box.Equals(sender)
    Next
End Sub
```

There might be some surgery side-effects, I didn't see any but didn't test it thoroughly.  I recommend you do *not* actually do this, the feature is massively undiscoverable.  No user will ever realize that a double-click now does something special.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I am investigating all answers provided.  I understand this is nonstandard behavior, and I have good reasons.  Very briefly: 1) A means to select only one is highly desirable as there may be 20 pre-checked boxes.  2) I am replacing an existing app which had similar behavior.  3) I will add a tooltip "Double-click to select only Steve". 4) Adding new objects do do this can clutter the screen. 5) This does not interfere at all with standard behavior.  Consider for example: Ctrl-Mousewheel to zoom.  It's a great feature which many users never discover, but so what?

Comment: This is the one I'm going with, but adding two caveats:  First, in the RaiseEvent line I changed EventArgs to MouseEventArgs.  Second, the click event is still firing prematurely... It should wait for the period defined by SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime so that a click doesn't fire if a doubleclick is about to happen.  I believe such a delay occurs natively for most objects that support doubleclick.  (As-is, code that's run upon changing checkstate occurs twice for a doubleclick, which isn't ideal.)  I can work on that small issue later.  Thank you Hans, and others too.

Answer (score 2):

checkboxes do have a DoubleClick event.

**[CheckBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

**[DoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.doubleclick.aspx)**     Infrastructure. Occurs when the user double-clicks the CheckBox 
control.

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, the default behaviour is that the event isn't called.

What you can do though, is make your own class that inherits from CheckBox.
You will need to set the **[StandardDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx)** style. Using **[SetStyle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** method.
Then Override the **[OnDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ondoubleclick%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** method to catch it before the event is raised.

```
public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox {

 MyCheckBox()
 {
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick);
 }


 protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
 {
   Base.OnDoubleClick(e);
   //Do what ever you want... Like actually calling the DoubleClick event....
 }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to clarify that I'm using VB.NET 2008 Express, wherein most definitely there is no doubleclick event for checkboxes.

Comment: It's still .Net framework ... DoubleClick event has been around since .Net 1.1 ... Maybe it's not in the designer, but it is there.

Comment: Hmmm... This page regarding the doubleclick event for the checkbox (framework 3.5) says "the StandardClick and StandardDoubleClick enumerations are set to false" by default which means it's there, but it's not raised:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.doubleclick%28v=vs.90%29.aspx  How can I get the event to be raised?

Comment: @Paul : You're right, it was disabled by default. You can inherit from the class, and catch it with the OnEvent.... I've edited my answer with an example

Comment: @Paul: the enumerations can be set with SetStyle()

Answer (score 2):

<del>You can use the MouseDoubleClick, but the event is not exposed through the Design interface. To use it, add the following line to the constructor or the load event of your form:

checkBox1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(checkBox1_MouseDoubleClick);

This assumes a checkBox1.MouseDoubleClick method, like the one below:

void checkBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}</del>

Okay, the last example doesn't work, you are right; The DoubleClick event is never raised. So, this can be a little "hacky", but will work:

Extend the `CheckBox` class, creating a `CheckboxExtended` class, for example. In this class, we override the `WndProc` method and intercept windows double click messages. The example code follows:

```
public class CheckBoxExtended : CheckBox
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Threat the message first
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            var lparam = m.LParam.ToInt32();
            var x = lparam & 0x0000FFFF;
            var y = (int) ((lparam & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);

            OnMouseDoubleClick(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 2, x, y, 0));
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

<del>I'm still not sure about parsing the LParam to get mouse position. Just give me a couple of seconds.</del>

To use the class, just do as I've said previously:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        checkBoxExtended1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(checkBoxExtended1_MouseDoubleClick);
    }

    void checkBoxExtended1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Test");
    }

}
```

Of course, I'm assuming a form with a `CheckBoxExtended` on it.

**EDIT:** Heck, I just discovered that I was using a binary or instead of a binary and. Now the source is fixed and should return the right coordinates.

**EDIT 2:** Okay, I've created the class in VB, but I've not tested it -- my skills in VB aren't that great either. One tip: you can write another DoubleClick event yourself for the extended class, and add the necessary decoration (attributes) to enable the Designer to show it.

```
Public Class CheckboxExtended
    Inherits CheckBox

    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H203

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

        'Threat the message first
        If m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK Then

            Dim lparam = m.LParam.ToInt32()
            Dim x = lparam And &HFFFF
            Dim y = ((lparam And &HFFFF0000) >> 16)

            OnMouseDoubleClick(New MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 2, x, y, 0))
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yikes.  This tempts me to just use label (which ironically DOES expose doubleclick) and put a little square next to it that I can check in code so that it "looks" checked.  LOL - I won't actually do this but it occurred to me.  Also it seems that with your solution the "single" click event would NOT be delayed in your solution.  (As I mentioned, it's best if clicking once doesn't run code for a few milliseconds until we're sure a doubleclick won't happen.)  I may be mistaken but I believe that objects that normally expose doubleclick delay the click event (imperceptibly) for just this reason.

Comment: @Paul, that's also my guess. Windows has a delay to consider a double click, which is actually configurable ("Double-click speed" in Mouse configuration menu on Control Panel). This solution accounts for that as well, since we're leaving windows in charge.

Comment: Your solution appears to be approximately the same as Yochai's except that he (or she) is using SetStyle to set the StandardDoubleClick enumeration.  Although I did claim I could translate from C#, (and I usually can) I'm still a VB guy and in this case I might not be as smart as I thought I was.  If you could VB-ize this it would be helpful.

Comment: @Paul: fixed the source for the coordinates. I'll try to write this as VB code.

Comment: @Paul: VB example added. See if it runs alright, otherwise post here again and I'll try and fix whatever problems it might have.

Comment: Bruno, I just wanted to drop a thank you. I went with Hans' answer (which is similar) but I appreciate your efforts.  Upvoted your comment too.